# The background color of the UITableView or UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am kind of stuck on this very stupid issue. When I display the `UITableView` I see it like this:

[image]

As you can see the empty rows with no data are black. I have checked and made sure that the `UITableView` background is set to white, the `UITableView` background is set to white. One other thing I noticed is that I cannot scroll the above table view.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set image on backgroundView very easy and elegant

```
 tableView.backgroundView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellbg_normal.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
```

Comment: tableView.backgroundColor did the trick! I am surprised that even though I set the background using the designer it did not work.

Comment: Sometimes there can be performance issues with having alot of cells with transparent backgrounds.  If you encounter this issue, see the comment below on the answer provided by ansible. 

His code is referencing the wrong delegate method. I've attached a link to the docs there as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView.background=[UIColor whiteColor];
```

and set the background of all views in your custom cell as `clearColor`

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the background on the cell's ContentView (this one is set to green).

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    [[cell contentView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:128/255.f blue:0 alpha:1]];
    return cell;
}
```

Source - http://www.zenbrains.com/blog/en/2010/06/color-de-fondo-de-celdas-vacias/.

Comment: Thanks! I used the designer to set the background of the cell to white  and it gives me the same black background. I tried changing the contentView to white same thing.

Comment: Background color needs to be set in

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

which is part of the UITableViewDelegate protocol.

It should not be set in 

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

which is part of the UITableViewDataSource protocol.

See the docs here for comments https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW8